# Unable to load the source file details into mysql database using TALEND tool

Tags: talend, data-integration

I am new to talend.

I need to upload the incoming file details into MySQL tables.

Please, can you provide me an example (Talend ETL) to propagate the primary key from one table (tMysqlOutput) to another table (tMysqlOutput) through Talend? This primary key will act as foreign key for another table. I am struggling with this.

Existing scenario:

```
filedelimiter --> tmap --> stage --> tmap --> master table
```

(I want this primary key from this table table to child table)

This is the tool we are using http://www.talend.com/

Comment: Is the primary key generated by MySQL or by the tMap ? Please update your question in order to include such information.

Comment: The primary key is generated by mysql.

Comment: I think you should read the inserted data with a tMySQLInput and map the primary key created by mySQL with the child table in a tMap. The join should be done between inserted entries and the child table based on your own business key. Could you give us an example of both schema (master and child tables) and an example of data